# What's the difference between a memory arena and a memory allocator?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

This is more a semantic question than a coding question....

What's the difference between a memory arena and a memory allocator?

I'm working in C++ and I'm seeing some memory management libs using concepts like "memory arena", "memory allocator" and sometimes both in the same lib.

I know what an allocator is; I'm just not sure what a memory arena is if it's not just another word for allocator.

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say "arena" represents a pool of memory available for allocation, and an "allocator" is the function that provides you with a chunk of memory in that arena. I'm not 100% sure of this though, so I won't make it an answer ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Memory arena" typically means a large lump (or collection of lumps) of memory from which smaller lumps are allocated. The word "pool" is also commonly used for such a thing.

"Memory allocator" typically means the software that determines how to allocate memory from an arena.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, a "memory arena" is a pool of memory that a "memory allocator" allocates memory from. But I wouldn't be surprised to see "memory arena" used as a synonym for "memory allocator".